# Error when importing com.google, com.android.internal.Telephony, etc

Tags: android, android-layout, android-source

I've downloaded the android source code for CallLog, Contacts, Dialing from [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Contacts).

But now, when I try to import this package on Eclipse, imports like:

> com.google,
>   com.android.internal.Telephony,
>   com.android.internal.R,
>   com.google.android.collect,
>   android.provider.ContactsContract.Intents.UI,
>   android.provider.ContactsContract.SearchSnippetColumns,
>   android.provider.ContactsContract.ProviderStatus,
>   android.provider.ContactsContract.ContactCounts,
>   android.content.IContentService,
>   android.provider.ContactsContract.Intents.UI

And many other imports, show errors saying it **cannot be resolved**.

So my question is, why it shows this errors? Why I cant implement it without this errors? I use the Google APIs, I've created the project from an existing source code, but I dont know why this happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're sure that you have set up the Android SDK correctly, you should try to 'clean' your Eclipse project.

This usually solves import related errors in Eclipse for me.

Comment: And you are sure that the packages are existing and the references are correct?

Comment: I think you'll have to wait for someone with a different approach then.

Answer (score 0):

Try right clicking the solution / project in the project explorer and choose "fix" near the bottom.

Comment: There is no "fix" near the bottom. And are you sure is this the solution? Thanks.

Comment: ermm, "fix project setup"....this has resolved dependency issues for me in the past yes.